# How to get nested JSON data in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am using axios to fetch data from api.
My router is:

```
<Route exact path='/device/:id/update' render={(props) => <DeviceTypeUpdate {...props} />} />
```

My componentDidMount is :

```
componentDidMount() {
  console.log('------this.props.match.id----', this.props.match.params.id)
  const ied = this.props.match.params.id
  axios({
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/devicetypeget/'+ied,
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    }
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    return response;
  })
  .then(function (devicetype) {
    this.setState(function () {
      return {devicetype: devicetype, isLoaded: true}
    })
  }.bind(this))
  .catch(function (error) {
    this.setState(function () {
      return {error, isLoaded: true}
    })
  }.bind(this))
}
```

In my render method, I tried to log data in console, as given below:

```
const {error, isLoaded, devicetype} = this.state
console.log('----error----', error);
console.log('----devicetype in render----', devicetype.data);
```

devicetype.data prints out the JSON object which has nested data in it as given below:

```
assignment_date: {$date: 1548744545634}
device_elements: {type: "switch", name: "board", state: "some state"}
dev_stage: "PLANNING"
type_description: "some description"
type_name: "Board"
_id: 1
```

when I console.log(devicetype.data.device_elements) or any other attribute 
It throws an error `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'type_name' of undefined"`

What am I doing wrong. Please help me

Comment: What is the initial value of `this.state.devicetype`? My guess is that your component is rendering before `this.state.devicetype.data` is set in response to the axios call, so the initial render is trying to access an object that does not exist (yet).

Comment: @christian my initial value of this.state.devicetype is {} empty object.

Comment: If my component is rendering before "this.state.devicetype.data" is set to the axios call. Then how do I fix it.

Comment: It depends on how you want your UI to handle this case. Usually this behavior is desirable as it gives you the opportunity to show a "Loading..." message while your data is being loaded, otherwise your component would not render until your data is loaded. You can add an if-statement to your `render()` function to handle the case where data is not yet loaded. In pseudocode: `if (dataIsNotLoaded) displayLoadingMessage else displayData`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do conditional check before accessing nested objects like

```
   if(devicetype.data){
       console.log(devicetype.data.device_elements);
       console.log(devicetype.data.type_name);
   }
```

Comment: This method worked. Can you explain why it is necessary to do a conditional check before accessing nested object. Thanks

Comment: because devicetype.data is undefined or null on initial render but you are directly accessing devicetype.data.type_name which won’t work because in initial render devicetype.data is undefined